# Shared payment between two parties from one payment

Tags: flutterflow

Hello I am working on a project in which we need to add some share between two parties (x/y) for doing a particular work. For payment I am using Stripe API. I am trying to integrate it to my flutterlow app in which "Y" gets some amount of money paid for the services that he has done.

I was not able to find a solution for this.